# Spring boot: reference pom properties from application.properties in tests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, junit5

This is my src/**test**/resources/**application.yml**:

```
app:
  name: Configuration And Profiles
  desc: This is an app to try out ${app.name}
  version: @modelVersion@
```

I'm just trying to get the model version from my **pom file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
...
```

The test:

```
@WebMvcTest(ProfilingController.class)
public class RestControllerTest {

    @Value("${app.version}")
    private String version;

    @Test
    public void testHelloEnv() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("VERSION: " + version);

    }
}
```

The error I get:

```
org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: while scanning for the next token
found character '@' that cannot start any token. (Do not use @ for indentation)
 in 'reader', line 4, column 12:
      version: @modelVersion@
               ^
```

The funny part is that I got the same property in the src/**main**/resource/application.yml, but in that case when I run the app normally, version: @modelVersion is correctly populated from pom and I can get the version without issues. It's like test's application.yml is not aware of pom.xml

any thoughts?

NOTE: using '@modelVersion' between single quotes prevents the error but I get the string @modelVersion instead of its value 4.0.0

Tech:

- Spring boot version: 2.5.6
- Junit version: Jupiter (5)
- Maven version: 3.8.3

Comment: Why do you need the modelVersion in a spring boot test?

Comment: nope, I don't need it. I just picked that property randomly as a proof of concept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.properties-and-configuration.expand-properties.maven) resource filtering is enabled by the `spring-boot-starter-parent`

That is not the case for 'test' properties, so if you need this,
you need to enable filtering in the test-resources:

in your pom.xml

```xml
    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    ...
    </build>
```

Comment: worked like a charm! I reached the part where I added a new directory resource but wasn't aware of filtering. Thanks a lot!